# Let n be any positive integer. Find all primitive pythagorean triples which have 2^n as a side.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Q. Let n be any positive integer. Find all primitive pythagorean triples which have 2^n as a side.

So here is what I have;

We see that 2^n = 2∙2∙2∙∙∙2, n times, and is clearly an even number. Then we see 2^n can be the side x, for where x=2st, by our definition of primitive pythagorean triplet. That is 2^n=2st ⇒ 2^n-1=st ⇒

not sure if I am headed in the right direction, and if I am where to go from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  So now you have $st=2^{n-1}$, with $s$ and $t$ relatively prime and of opposite parity.  Can you figure out $s,t$ from that?  There are not many choices.

Comment: It would have seemingly endless answers for any increasing n? I know a simple example n=2 => s=1, t=2 as part of the 3,4,5 triangle but how can I tell if there is a definitive amount.

Comment: Next try $n=3$.  We need $st=4$.  There are not many ways to factor $4$, especially with one of the factors odd.  For $n=4$, you have to factor $8$ with one of the factors odd.

Comment: So the only way to do would be with s=4, t=1, and then for 2^4 = 16 , the only way to do so would be s=8, t= 1? So all P.P.T.'s have the form of s=2^(n-1) and t=1?

Comment: and we know that the only integers that divide 2^n are 2 and 1

Comment: No need to use $n-1$ instead of $n$, but yes :)

Comment: That is right.  You get $s=2^{n-1},t=1$ giving a triangle of $2^{2n-2}-1,2^n,2^{2n-2}+1$.  For $n=3$ this is $15,8,17$ and $n=4$ gives $63,16,65$

Answer (score 1):

$$ a = k\cdot(m^2 - n^2)   ,\ \, b = k\cdot(2mn) ,\ \, c = k\cdot(m^2 + n^2)\\
\implies b=2^n\\
\implies mnk=2^{n-1}\\
\implies k=\dfrac{2^{n-1}}{mn}$$
Thus,
$$a=\dfrac{2^{n-1}}{mn}\cdot(m^2 - n^2)=\dfrac{2^{n-1}m}{n}-\dfrac{2^{n-1}n}{m}\\
\implies b=\dfrac{2^{n-1}m}{n}+\dfrac{2^{n-1}n}{m}$$
Then, since $m$ and $n$ relatively prime and of opposite parity, you can figure out their values. Substitute the result into the above equation.

Comment: Not sure I understand what's going on here.. are you taking multiples of the general equation by k?